# References for these two theorems?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, reference-request

Here are the two statements :

> Let $f:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. If there exists a countable set $W\subseteq [a,b]$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b] \setminus W$ and if there exists $L>0$ such that for all $x\in [a,b] \setminus W$ : $\vert f'(x)\vert \le L$. Then $\vert f(b) - f(a)\vert \le M\vert b-a\vert$.

The second one :

> Let $f:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function and $g:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a nondecreasing continuous function. If there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in J}$ ($J$ can be finite or infinite) which takes its values in $[a,b]$ and such that for all $x\in [a,b]\setminus \{x_n ; \ n\in J \}$ : $f$  and $g $ admits a right derivative in $x$ (note $f'_r(x)$ and $g'_r(x) \ $) and $\vert f'_r(x) \vert \le g'_r(x)$. Then $\vert f(b)-f(a) \vert \le g(b) -g(a)$.

The two theorems, of course, share similarities. Apparently, they come from Denjoy but I could not find any references or informations about it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would look into Dideudonne: Foundations of modern analysis.

Comment: @PhoemueX Indeed thank you ! The two statements appear in the book you suggest under the section "Mean value theorem" !